Change run location of a github project using npm run dev
I am using this github project: https://suno.gcui.ai/ and it defaults to running locally on localhost:3000. I am running this in a webserver, not on my local machine, so I want it to run on the webservers url. When I run npm run dev it displays this:
How can I change the run location of this project?
